# LINQ group by into a new list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two classes

```
public class groupedDoc { 
   public string gr_id = "";
   public string id = "";
   public string name = "";
   public subrec subRec = new subrec();
}

public class subrec {
   public List<record> record = new List<record>();
   '''
}
```

I want to group a `List<record> allrecord` based on the id and name into the object called `groupedDoc`.

This is what I do

```
var groupedList = allrecord.ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.id ,x.name})
.Select(grp => new groupedRec
{
     gr_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     id = grp.FirstOrDefault().id,
     name = grp.FirstOrDefault().name
})
.ToList();
```

But I also want to return the grouped record into the `subrec.record`. I tried
`subRec.record = grp.ToList()` but get "invalid initializer member declarator". So anyone can help  me to achieved that?

Comment: Use `grp.Key.id` and `grp.Key.name`

Answer (score 1):

You have to also initialize subrec in the statement:

```cs
var groupedList = allrecord.ToList().GroupBy(x => new { x.id ,x.name})
.Select(grp => new groupedRec
{
     gr_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
     id = grp.Key.id,
     name = grp.Key.name,
     subRec = new subrec()
     {
         record = grp.ToList()
     }
})
.ToList();
```

I've replaced your `id =`  and `name =`  assignments with what I believe you were going for, to save creating more enumerators for the grouped records. As an aside, you should rename `record` to `records` as it represents more than one record.

I'd also recommend following [Microsoft's naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions) so that your code is easier for other people to follow, etc.